# hosting for a react application

Tags: reactjs, iis, redux

​I have a website built in reactjs with redux with webpack configurations. In local its running on `localhost:3000` url.

I am using react-redux async mode of loading required modules (using get component and injecting needed reducers upon request)

My route configuration has `path ='/login', '/customers', '/customer/view/:id' , '/customer/edit/:Id'` etc with few other routes as well.

When I run in local or host the application in IIS, my URL looks like localhost:3000/login , localhost:3000/customers etc.

Now as per our requirement, I am looking to host my application under a sub application say 'sub'. For this, I changed 'publicpath' of webpack config file and expected everything to work normally. ​ But it didnt work.​
To make it work under a sub application, I introduced a dummy component with 'sub' as route and added child components within it. 
In Angular, I found this command `ng build --base-href "/subfolder/" --prod` which provides minified files which when hosted on IIS it was working fine without any more changes. Is there any easy way to do some thing similar to this in react?

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json` you can add

```
"homepage": "/sub"
```

and deploy the project as the name `sub`

Comment: I have to take a look at it. I remember I tried it with no luck. But I will check it again

Comment: looking at https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#homepage and it says i have to provide a valid url. I am not sure what my prod URL could be.

Comment: Your UI's context path is enough. full URL is not required. its working for me

Comment: you mean "homepage": "/sub" this way? VS code is giving warning for this

Comment: Let me know where you have deployed this application?

Comment: I have deployed it in IIS